# Can we derive a place name from longitude & latitude coordinates in a URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, latitude-longitude

I'm wondering if there is a way to get some kind of place name or place description from longitude and latitude coordinates. I Googled for a solution before posting here, but I didn't find anything. I found information about geocoding and reverse geocoding, and these are interesting, but I don't think I can put that into practice, for what I'm trying to accomplish here. Please correct me if I am wrong though!

Maybe there is some kind of API call that let's people do this kind of thing. Not sure. Maybe this is a screen scraping exercise. I can use Selenium or Beautiful Soup, if necessary. What I'm trying to do is get is loop through records in a Pandas DF and get something consistent, like 'Yankee Stadium', based on lat=40.76 and lon=-73.97. All my lat and lng coordinates are correct, but unfortunately people enter pretty much whatever they want into the 'place_name' field. So, I'm getting 'Yankee_Stadium, 'Yankee_Stad', 'Yankee_Subway', 'Stad_Yankees', 'Yank_Stad', and all kinds of other combinations of descriptions, which is really one single place.

Here's a screen shot of Google Maps with lon & lat in the URL.

[image]

I think it would be very useful to get place descriptions from lat & ln coordinates!

This is just a wild guess, but maybe the code will start like this.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get ('https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yankee+Stadium/@40.8296466,-73.9283685,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2f42c5ae76971:0x4940c3d9559a1e08!8m2!3d40.8296426!4d-73.9261745')
```

Or maybe selenium is overkill, and Beautiful Soup is the way to go here...like this...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#Pandas/numpy for data manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#load URLs we want to scrape into an array
BASE_URL = ['https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yankee+Stadium/@40.8296466,-73.9283685,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2f42c5ae76971:0x4940c3d9559a1e08!8m2!3d40.8296426!4d-73.9261745']

#loading empty array for board members
places = []
#Loop through our URLs we loaded above
for b in BASE_URL:
    html = requests.get(b).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    #identify table we want to scrape
    place_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "dataTable"})


try:
#loop through table, grab each of the 4 columns shown (try one of the links yourself to see the layout)
    for row in place_table.find_all('tr'):
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        places.append(b, cols[0].text.strip())
except:
    print('nothing found...')
```

I've never been good at this screen scraping stuff. Anyway, the string I want seems to come after this 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' and before the first set of lat & lon coordinates!

Comment: you know that you can use Google API?

Comment: The Google API doesn't work on my work-computer; it's blocked. I can't move files off my work-computer to my own laptop.